# Why does Magento 1.9.2 "loadLayout" start to load products?

Tags: magento-1.9.2.1

***Does someone know why Magento likes to load products when being asked to just load the layout ?***

I just are walking through some Magento code from 1.9.2.
And i have writen a controller with just: loadLayout en renderLayout.
So i tought that i could change blocks between the two functions, but it turns out that is not the case for most of the 'core' blocks. For example in this block filling in the HTML Header is done if you say: "loadLayout".

Does anyone have experience with removing blocks that already 'changed' the global Magento world ?

For example: Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View

```
/**
 * Retrieve current product model
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
 */
public function getProduct()
{
    if (!Mage::registry('product') && $this->getProductId()) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId());
        Mage::register('product', $product);
    }
    return Mage::registry('product');
}
/**
     * Add meta information from product to head block
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/breadcrumbs');
        $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        if ($headBlock) {
            $product = $this->getProduct();
            $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
            if ($title) {
                $headBlock->setTitle($title);
            }
            $keyword = $product->getMetaKeyword();
            $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
            if ($keyword) {
                $headBlock->setKeywords($keyword);
            } elseif ($currentCategory) {
                $headBlock->setKeywords($product->getName());
            }
            $description = $product->getMetaDescription();
            if ($description) {
                $headBlock->setDescription( ($description) );
            } else {
                $headBlock->setDescription(Mage::helper('core/string')->substr($product->getDescription(), 0, 255));
            }
            if ($this->helper('catalog/product')->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
                $params = array('_ignore_category' => true);
                $headBlock->addLinkRel('canonical', $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, $params));
            }
        }

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

This is my test:

```
<?php
include_once('../initMage.php');
initMage();

$controller = initController('Gn_Test_IndexController');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
Mage::register('product', $product);
$controller->loadLayout();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explaining in this in full goes beyond a single Stack Exchange answer, the layout system could fill a small book (and [I've written that book](http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout)).

In short -- when you call `loadLayout` you're telling Magento

1. Merge all the Layout XML Update files (`app/design/area/theme/layout`) into one tree
2. Find the specific parts of that tree to use for this request
3. Use those specific parts of the tree to determine which block objects to instantiate, and then instantiate the block objects

It's the last part of #3 that's throwing you -- when Magento instantiates a block via the layout it calls `_construct` and and `_prepareLayout` in the block.  These methods, in turn, will often do things like load a product collection.

To finish the above, when you call `renderLayout` you're telling Magento "call the root block's `toHtml` method, which renders the root block's `phtml` template, which cascades to the other block's `phtml` templates via `getChildHtml` (this also sometimes triggers direct instantiation and rendering of other block objects)

> Does anyone have experience with removing blocks that already 'changed' the global Magento world ?

In general, you *probably* don't want to do this.  Other blocks and code may rely on that state you're looking to alter, and removing it may cause fatal errors.

If you **really** want to do this, I'd look into the following events

```
controller_action_layout_load_before
controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before
controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before
```

and then directly modifying the layout and/or layout update object (from the passed in observer) to remove the XML responsible for creating the block you want to remove.

Comment: Thanx Alan Storm ! I'm just playing around with Magento CE and wanted a `other` controller load a `product_view` but than with the 'product.info' block swaped (without changing xml). I tought this would be very straight forward. Turns out it's not the case. But i didn't look at the events. I changed the 'Mage_Core_Block_Profiler', so i can see all the 'DISPATCH EVENT:', 'OBSERVER:' events. Thanx for the Advice. I like your web-page/blog, you and Vinai have teached me everything about Magento. Thanx.